# jQuery-Mobile: Scrolling stops working when javascript function is called in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a function that I use to take information from a JSON file and display it dynamically. I dynamically create multiple pages depending on the amount of elements in the array. It works perfectly when I apply it to one page but when I apply it to multiple pages (which I need to) the scroll feature stops to work for no apparent reason. I changed the second page back to its original state and the first page started to work again. Here's my JS function and if you could please tell me whats going on I'd appreciate it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){ 
  var info="";
  var dpages="";
  var pageno=1;  
  var imp= "Json/empirical.json";
  $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
     $.each(data.tcontent, function(i, item) {
        if(item.Name=='Skin and Soft Tissue Infections'){
           var search=item.Variations;
           $.each(search, function(j, subitem) {

            info += '<a href="#Paged'+ pageno + ' " data-role="button" data-mini="true">'+ subitem.condition +'</a><br>';

            dpages += '<div data-role="page"  data-theme="a" id="Paged' + pageno + '"> <div data-role="header" data-theme="c"><a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back"> Back</a> <h2>'+ subitem.condition +'</h2> </div> <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Paged '+ pageno +'_Content">  <p class="infotexttitle">Likely Organisms: </p> ' + subitem.organisms + ' <p class="infotexttitle"> Antimicrobial & Dosage </p> ' + subitem.antimicrobial + '  <p class="infotexttitle"> Alternative Antimicrobial: </p> ' + subitem.alternative + ' <div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d"> <h3> Comments: </h3> <p class="guidelinetext"> ' + subitem.comments + ' </p></div> </div> <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"> <h2>(c) Darragh O Connor </h2></div> </div></div>';



            pageno++;                        
        });
    }
  $("#texts").empty().append(info).collapsibleset().trigger('create');
  $.mobile.pageContainer.append(dpages);
  }); }); });
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on this "_It works perfectly when I apply it to one page but when I apply it to multiple pages (which I need to) the scroll feature stops to work for no apparent reason_"? Call same function on other pages?

Comment: @Omar Basically the function is very adaptable. In the if loop if I change the item.Name then it will generate completely new content from the same JSON file. So I have a large array of information and I use the same function to access different pieces of information, depending on what I want to display. If I call the function on only one page then it works perfectly. But when I use the same function in more than one page then the scrolling stops working on all the pages the function is called on. Do you understand?

Comment: So, you create more pages each time you call that function. Make sure that all tags are properly closed, test functions on a small json array until you find the problem.